# Dynamic cursor using variables with null values in PL\SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Can anyone could help me with this issue, please?
I have a cursor defined like this:

```
 CURSOR c_cursorName (
      paramA   IN VARCHAR2,
      paramB   IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
      SELECT tableA.id, tableA.name
        FROM tableA
       WHERE     tableA.fieldA = paramA
             AND (paramB IS NULL OR tableA.fieldB = paramB);
```

Why I'm doing this? Because I want to reuse this cursor in two different cases:

1. when I pass a paramB value to return all the rows in tableA
   where fieldA is equal to paramA value and fieldB is equal to paramB;
2. When I don't pass any value in paramB (`null` value), and I want to return all the rows in tableA where fieldA is simply equal to paramA (and I don't care about fieldB);

The problem: When I pass `null` in paramB, my explain plan increase dramatically and I have performance issues.

The easy way to do this is creating two different cursors, one for each case. But I'm trying to find a good and clever solution without the need of creating a new index or a new cursor.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
cursor c_cursorname (parama in varchar2,
                     paramb in varchar2)
is
with results as (select tablea.id,
                        tablea.name,
                        tablea.fieldb
                 from   tablea
                 where  tablea.fielda = parama)
select id, name
from   results
where  paramb is null
union all
select id, name
from   results
where  fieldb = paramb;
```

Oracle should be able to short-circuit which of the two queries in the union all is run, based on the value of paramb.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly modified solution based on the "exclusive union all" approach from @Boniest:

I do not use a subquery to avoid possible materialization of it and I add explicit 
check on the NULL / NOT NULL of the paramb to perform always only one part of the UNION ALL.

```
 SELECT tableA.id, tableA.name
        FROM tableA
       WHERE     tableA.fieldA = :parama
             AND  :paramb IS NULL 
UNION ALL
 SELECT tableA.id, tableA.name
        FROM tableA
       WHERE     tableA.fieldA = :parama
             AND :paramb IS NOT NULL 
             AND fieldb = :paramb
```

I assume an index on  tableA (fieldA, fieldB).

This leads to the execution plan below.

For `paramb is NULL` index range scan on `fieldA` is done,

for `paramb is NOT NULL` index range scan on `fieldA, fieldB` is done.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |             |   101 |  4962 |     5  (40)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                    |             |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER                      |             |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLEA      |   100 |  4900 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLEA_IDX1 |    40 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |   FILTER                      |             |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLEA      |     1 |    62 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLEA_IDX1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SET$1
   2 - SEL$1
   3 - SEL$1 / TABLEA@SEL$1
   4 - SEL$1 / TABLEA@SEL$1
   5 - SEL$2
   6 - SEL$2 / TABLEA@SEL$2
   7 - SEL$2 / TABLEA@SEL$2

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(:PARAMB IS NULL)
   4 - access("TABLEA"."FIELDA"=TO_NUMBER(:PARAMA))
   5 - filter(:PARAMB IS NOT NULL)
   7 - access("TABLEA"."FIELDA"=TO_NUMBER(:PARAMA) AND "FIELDB"=TO_NUMBER(:PARAMB))
```

Comment: Both solutions are great! But I have one performance issue because I need to play with indexes in the REAL tables here (tableA don't exists, of course). Thanks!